# Mapping fetched data instead of Object.keys()

Tags: javascript, object

I have this code (I made it short so I get directly to the point):

```
async function getData(){
const response = await fetch("api_url_here")
const data = await response.json()

someElement.innerHTML = `
<select>
        ${ data.map( info => `<option>${info}</option>` ) }
</select>
`
}
```

A programmer told me that it's not right to map the 'data' directly, instead I should use:

```
 ${ Object.keys(data).map( info => `<option>${info}</option>` ) }
```

Can anyone tell me what is the difference.

Comment: Please share the structure of the `data` and what you want to show.

Comment: If `data` isn't an array, the first won't work. The second maps the keys of `data`, which you might want if `data` is an object, but probably won't want if it is an array (ie: it will give the indexes if it's an array)

Comment: I am fetching this API: (https://breakingbadapi.com/api/characters) which returns an Array.

Based on Nick's answer, that's why I don't see the difference.

Comment: @drnour Yeah, the second definitely isn't what you want (unless you're after the indexes of the array for some reason?) if that's what your API responds with. The first  will still cause issues since you're going to be converting your object to a string when it gets interpolated, and then your array into a comma-separated string

Comment: @NickParsons You're absolutely right, I solved the comma problem by using .join('') but I think this is just an extra work for what I want to achieve here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is a [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) of `Array` in javascript. `data` can be a `Object` so it doesn't always have `map` method, while `Object.keys(data)` is always an `Array` of all data keys.

Comment: The API responds with an array though, so it will have a map method

Comment: @Yicheng Thank you, that's exactly the info I want to know.

Comment: @drnour your api returns an array though... so `Object.keys()` would only be needed if it isn't an array :P

Comment: @NickParsons yes I know, but I wanted to know the difference in general for future project maybe. Thank you so much